# My php checkRE function shows the answer right but I think it is wrong

Tags: php, regex

The RegEx is `[\w|\W]*\s[\w|\W]*` and the string is `aaab@ asd123`  because I think `[\w|\W]*` is equal to `\w*|\W*` which means multiple of words character or non-words character... how can it have both word and non-word character together like `aab@` ?

Comment: How comes that something is right and wrong the same time? Don't get you...

Comment: When you are **sure it is wrong**, get back to us

Comment: Your regex matches all there is, then 0+ whitespaces, and then again any 0+ chars. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiICPL/1). Right now, it is just not clear what you want to do. Note `[\w|\W]*` != `\w*|\W*`. Maybe you need [`(\S+)\s(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oiICPL/2).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Your string appears to be space delimited, so you could just use `explode(" ", $s)`. The answer below is to just explain how regex works.

I believe you misunderstood the `[\w|\W]*` and `\w*|\W*`: the first one matches any 0+ characters, and the second one matches either 0+ word chars or 0+ non-word chars.

You seem to want to match 0+ non-whitespace characters, use `\S+`:

```
\S+\s+\S+
```

Or, to capture the two non-whitespace parts:

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

The `+` will make the pattern match one or more occurrences of a non-whitespace pattern at a stretch.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wqlav2/1)